# Vision: what is the difference between on-off ganglion cells and lateral inhibition?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, vision

Is 'lateral inhibition' just a term for the biological basis of the functioning of the on-center (or off-center) ganglion cells?
Or do these terms describe separate processes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**
Retinal center-surround receptive fields are an example of lateral inhibition. It occurs elsewhere in the nervous system too.

**Background**
Center-surround receptive fields are indeed *an example* of [lateral inhibition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_inhibition), where the ON field suppress the OFF field through lateral inhibition. The center-surround connectivity in the retina (Fig. 1) is indeed the most well-known example of this kind of circuitry. However, lateral inhibition occurs in other sensory systems too, for example auditory and olfactory neurons [(Bakshi & Ghosh, 2017)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128113189000260). For more information on the retinal circuitry underlying center/surround inhibition see [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/42787/9943).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Bakshi & Ghosh (2017), *Handbook of Neural Computation*: 487-513](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128113189000260)</sub>.

[image]
<sup>Fig. 1. Retinal circuitry underlying On-OFF center-surround conncetivity in ganglion cells. source: [New York University](https://www.cns.nyu.edu/~david/courses/perception/lecturenotes/ganglion/ganglion.html)</sup>